# android studio Java implementation 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3' How to configure the library

Tags: java, xml, build.gradle

It is saying "Failed to resolve: com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app"

```
`<com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView 
android:id="@+id/swipeView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MissingClass" 
/>`

This is the error it is showing have been trying for weeks now nothing have tried on google and youtube seem to work 
Have tried to use the lower version nothing have tried the following
```

1. To rebuild the project
2. To restart the project
3. To clean the project
4. To import the library manually nothing is happning not sure what am doing wrong
   Nothing is working this is the xml file which is not showing saying missing class

I was expecting the xml class to be imported so i can finish the app but that error has done me bad

```
`<com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView 
android:id="@+id/swipeView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MissingClass"
```

/>`
your help will be appreciated thanks in advance for your help.